# Blazor routing object parameter

Tags: blazor-server-side

Can we use object parameters with blazor like this?

```
@page "/account/login/"
@page "/account/login/{Customer}"
@using Model

@(Customer?.Name ?? "Empty")

@code {
   [Parameter]
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, simple types only(int, string, etc). I would advise against using this type of binding for strings. Reason being a URL has reserved characters which get converted unless they are in a query string appended to the end of the URL. In addition, if your strings contain slashes, blazor will truncate the string. For example

navigating to "/account/login/test/123" will result in id=test.

```
@page "/account/login/"
@page "/account/login/{id}"
@using Model

@(Customer?.Name ?? "Empty")

@code {
   [Parameter]
   public string id{ get; set; }
}
```

There are a couple ways you can overcome this.

1. Send in an ID(see example code above) and perform a server request to get your data.
2. Create an in-app state manager service which you can use to pass objects between pages/components.

I had a situation where I needed to send a complex Identity token string into a blazor component via a URL, I used a query string and manually parsed the string using NavigationManager.Uri. This post is long enough, if you want to see an example of my querystring parse let me know.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use serialization. Something like this:

Person p = new Person();

```
 @{ string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
    var link = $"OtherComponentName/{json}";
  }
```

Remember about:

@using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: use "[MarkDown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)" format